# In iOS - How do I fit a UILabel to its text, without changing its position?

Tags: ios, uilabel, right-align, sizetofit

I'm calling `sizeToFit` on a `UILabel` which has right aligned text in it. It shrinks the height and width of the `UILabel`and fits the text to the top left of the `UILabel`.

Now...the position of the `UILabel` is incorrect. How can I make the `UILabel` stay in its original position (right aligned) or move it so it'll appear at its original position?

Once again - the problem is that the `sizeToFit` method is shrinking the width from the right side of the `UILabel`. It is treating the `UILabel` text as left aligned. But my text is right aligned. So, the right side border of the `UILabel` is where my text begins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check the widths before & after, then move the center of the view right by the difference / 2.

By the way, I think the "box" (frame) is shrunk in both directions, keeping the center intact.

Answer (score 16):

```
@implementation UILabel (Additions)

- (void)sizeToFitWithAlignmentRight {
    CGRect beforeFrame = self.frame;
    [self sizeToFit];
    CGRect afterFrame = self.frame;
    self.frame = CGRectMake(beforeFrame.origin.x + beforeFrame.size.width - afterFrame.size.width, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
}

@end
```